# Using FontAwesome Pro in Angular

Tags: angular, font-awesome

We're trying to switch out the free font-awesome 5 icons with pro icons in our Angular 10 application.
We're currently importing the free fonts by [Explicit Reference](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/explicit-reference.md) like so (in component.ts)

```
import { faLock } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

However, when using the pro icons it seems that no TypeScript files are provided, no `.d.ts` or ES module file seems to be included in the `@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro` npm package.

I know that we can go with the css solution, but we'd like to keep the explicitness and the tree-shaking possibilities, since we're using only a few of the icons.

My question is; is importing the pro icons in TS possible? It seems weird that the free icons allow this but the pro icons do not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Despite what the font awesome instructions says, you do not want `fortawesome/fontawesome-pro` package. I thrashed with this as well.

You just need `@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons`

Then you can import them as you do the free version:

`import { faComet } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';`

This is the same solution if you've been thrashing with the two different `IconDefinition` definitions between free and pro as a result of different `fontawesome-common-types`.

I think their "Installing the Pro version of Font Awesome" was not intended for people using `angular-fontawesome`, which is where I got confused.

Comment: Do you even need the api key then?

Comment: Yes sorry, you still need that bit of their tutorial in order to pull down the pro package from their private registry. Which is to either create a .npmrc file or the global config.